# How to Un-smart a smart object to apply threshold adjustment

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I can't apply threshold adjustment on a smart object. So I decided to unsmart it but can't find the way to do it. Please suggest.

Comment: There is no built in way to do it in a click or two, like the way you can u group layers. You can go edit the smart object contents, select all of the layers, right click one of them, choose duplicate layers and duplicate to the original document. There are scripts that do this as well. Also, you could add Threshold as Adjustment layer and clipping mask it to the Smart Object layer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to think about any backup copy.
just backup the layer, hide the original one, press 'B' to get the brush tool.. click on it and [image]

Click OK here.
Your original copy will remain uchanged.